# I'm looking for a way to turn output into an Octet

Tags: c#, string, binary

I'm writing a program that handles binary numbers in C#, after i convert the decimal numbers to binary, it will only take as much space as needed, but i need all 4 outputs to be octets (8 characters).

Let's say i convert 255.255.255.0 to binary i get the following outputs

```
11111111
11111111
11111111
0
```

what i would want is to get 7 zeroes behind the 0, as it needs to fill out all 8 spaces.
It is always 8 since I'm working with Subnet masks

I hope any of you can help, thank you. :)

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code. You can split the string and pad left each string.

```
string binary = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, (input.Split('.').Select(x => Convert.ToString(Int32.Parse(x), 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))).ToArray());
```